# How to copy files from multiple folders into one common folder using a defined list of files in a text file

Tags: powershell

I have a list of files that I need to extract from a large multi-tiered file structure into a single folder.  The list is compiled in a .txt file.  I can successful copy from one folder to another, but I need to find a way to do this recursively so that each folder in the file structure is reviewed for the target list of files and then copy only the target list of files to the destination

I have validated that I can copy a list of files from one folder to another using the get-content command

```
get-content pwrshelltest1.txt | foreach-object { copy-item -path $_ -destination "c:\testpshll\"}
```

I get errors when I place the -recurse command in my string regardless where I place it.

Comment: Why would you want to use `-Recurse`?. The question is about copying files from wherever they are into one common destination folder. Seems to me the code you have would do nicely, provided the textfile contains the full paths to the files to be copied over.

Comment: Thanks Theo - fair question.  Unfortunately, my text file does not contain the full path, but rather only the full file name.  This is what has caused me the challenge.  My list of files to be copied came from one source while the native files themselves are spread out all over our file server.  This is why I am trying to copy them from their homes into one collector folder.  Any idea how best to accomplish this in Powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regards to what you have commented, this could do what you want:

```
$searchRoot  = 'D:\'            #'# the rootpath on the file server to look for the files
$destination = 'C:\testpshll'
$fileNames   = Get-Content pwrshelltest1.txt

Get-ChildItem -Path $searchRoot -File -Recurse | 
    Where-Object { $_.DirectoryName -ne $destination -and $fileNames -contains $_.Name } | 
    Copy-Item -Destination $destination -WhatIf
```

Remove the `-WhatIf` switch once you are satisfied with the info shown in the console